# How can I set unique variable foreach item in array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I want to set a time stamp for each number, and then test each numbers timestamp against its self.

```
        var timestamp;
        nums=["1", "2", "3"];
        nums2=nums.map(myFunction);


        function myFunction(num) {

          setInterval(function() {

            var current_time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

            if (typeof timestamp !== "undefined" ) {
                if (current_time > (timestamp + 60)) {
                    timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                    console.log('time stamp reset');
                } else {
                    console.log('time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec');
                }
            } else {
                timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log('time stamp set');
            }

         }, 10000);

        }
```

****If I run script for 20 sec:****

**current output:**

```
time stamp set

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec

*(10 seconds later)*

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec
```

**desired output:**

```
time stamp set

time stamp set

time stamp set

*(10 seconds later)*

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec

time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to achieve. With how you're currently doing it, it's impossible for it to run for 20 seconds.. because it'll loop through your array in like 1ms...

Comment: Do you want to run the script twice with 10 seconds in between?

Comment: Agreed, this does nothing right now. Are you trying to go from `["1"."2"."3"]` to `[["1",timestamp],["2",timestamp],["3",timestamp]]` or perhaps `[{"1",timestamp},{"2",timestamp},{"3",timestamp}]`

Comment: @kemicofa I've changed my code to reflect the output. I've also edited my output.

Comment: The [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function should only be used to produce a second array of transformed elements. Use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate.

Comment: @ThomasSablik please refer to my updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand what you are trying to do here, so my answer is purely based on your **current output** and **desired output**.

Your `timestamp` variable is declared in the `global` scope, so the first time `myFunction` is called, it's value is `undefined`, but on subsequent calls it will be holding some value, resulting in your "current output".

To fix it, move `timestamp` variable inside `myFunction`.

```js
nums=["1", "2", "3"];
nums2=nums.map(myFunction);


function myFunction(num) {
  var timestamp;

  setInterval(function() {

    var current_time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    if (typeof timestamp !== "undefined" ) {
        if (current_time > (timestamp + 60)) {
            timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
            console.log('time stamp reset');
        } else {
            console.log('time stamp too young will reset after 60 sec');
        }
    } else {
        timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        console.log('time stamp set');
    }

 }, 10000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using function generators and setInterval

```js
const data = [];
//populate data
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){data.push(i)}

function * gen(){
  const timestamp = Date.now();
  let currentTimestamp;
  do{
     currentTimestamp = yield Date.now();
  }while(currentTimestamp - timestamp < 60000);
  return;
}

function run(){
  let iter = gen();
  let t = null;
  let i = 0;
  const res = [];
  const si = setInterval(function(){
    const {done,value} = iter.next(t);
    if(done){
      console.log("60 seconds have gone... reseting...")
      iter = gen();
      //reseting
      i = res.length = 0;
      
    }
    t = value;
    if(i >= data.length){
      console.log("waiting...");
      return;
    }
    console.log("Set timestamp");
    const d = [data[i], value];
    console.log(d);
    res[i++] = d;
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = run;
```